# Apex class to return date/time in user time zone

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, datetime

I have a flow that calculates a datetime to restart a paused action.  The problem is that the date is calculated and stored in GMT so the flow restarts at the wrong time.  I need to to "wake-up" based on the creator's timezone.  I've tried doing it with a formula field in the flow and as a field.  I've tried writing invocable Apex, but I'm not an Apex developer.  Can someone help me?

Comment: https://unofficialsf.com/flow-datetime-methods might help

Comment: If you already have some apex, all you need to do is use the TimeZone class to get the timezone's offset from GMT/UTC and add that to your date/time.